# How convert string to binary

Tags: c, string, byte

Im cant understand whats wrong with my code. All start to work good, but when my phrase "Hello, how are you" compiled, it start to print some other numbers and symbols.

Thank you in advance!`your text`

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void encode_string(const char string[], bool bytes[strlen(string)+1][8]){
    for(int j = 0; j <= bytes[strlen(string)+1][8]; j++){
        printf("%c: ", string[j]);
        for( int i = 7; i >= 0; i-- ) {
            printf( "%d", ( string[j] >> i ) & 1 ? 1 : 0 );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
 char* text = "Hello, how are you?";
    const int len = strlen(text);
    bool bytes1[len+1][8];
    encode_string(text, bytes1);
    for(int j = 0; j <= len; j++){
    printf("%c: ", text[j]);
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        printf("%d", bytes1[j][i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

Comment: for(int j = 0; j < len; j++) (not <=), iterate the array from 0 to len-1 (not len), is the first thing that caught me eyes.  Generally when you get random weird output in C, more often than not is a memory corruption issue.

Comment: You are *using* the passed `bytes` array in your `encode_string` function but I can't see anywhere in your code where you ever *set* any elements of that array.

Comment: What do you want it to do, first of all? Should the `encode_string` have output, or `main` have output?

Answer (score 0):

You're not allocating memory to string which you are passing. which leads to UB. I removed string size parameter in function `encode_string`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


void encode_string(const char string[])
{
    size_t len = strlen(string);
    char *binary = malloc(len*8 + 1);  //each char is one byte (8 bits) and + 1 at the end for null terminator
    for(int j = 0; j <= len; j++){
        printf("%c: ", string[j]);
        for( int i = 7; i >= 0; i-- ) {
            printf( "%d", ( string[j] >> i ) & 1 ? 1 : 0 );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
 char* text = "Hello, how are you?";
    const int len = strlen(text);
    bool bytes1[len+1][8];
    encode_string(text);
    for(int j = 0; j <= len; j++){
    printf("%c: ", text[j]);
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        printf("%d", bytes1[j][i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}

Output:
H: 01001000
e: 01100101
l: 01101100
l: 01101100
o: 01101111
,: 00101100
 : 00100000
h: 01101000
o: 01101111
w: 01110111
 : 00100000
a: 01100001
r: 01110010
e: 01100101
 : 00100000
y: 01111001
o: 01101111
u: 01110101
?: 00111111
: 00000000
H: 192900192900
e: 192900192900
l: 192900192900
l: 192900192900
o: 192900192900
,: 192900192900
 : 192900192900
h: 192900192900
o: 00000000
w: 010064000
 : 000064000
a: 02000400
r: 00000000
e: 00000000
 : 00000000
y: 00000000
o: 00000000
u: 00000000
?: 00000000
: 2151941531301348500


...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit console.
```

Comment: `binary` appears to be unused and a memory leak?

Comment: The function bool is mandatory)